# Join condition between class and course tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, data-warehouse, peoplesoft

so this question might make more sense to persons working in higher education.

I have class table with class start date and class end date along with course code and institution fields, I also have course table with course effective date,course expiration date, course_code and institution fields.

Previously the logic was to join on course_code, institution and the class start date was between course effective date and course expiration date. (see example below)

This join condition needs to be rewritten now as there are some classes belonging to a course that start before the course effective date and these classes were getting dropped during inner join.

Question - As I do not have any other fields to join on except for institution and course_code, is there any way I can rewrite this piece of code? I tried to change the join to outer join and it is creating duplicates.

PS:- I am new to much of this stuff so any suggestion is very helpful.

```
  Select crse_id, institution, class_start_date, class_end_date
  FROM PS_CLASS_TBL class
  Inner join PS_CRSE_CATALOG CATALOG ON 
  (
  CATALOG.CRSE_ID = class.CRSE_ID and
  Catalog.INSTITUTION = class.INSTITUTION 
  AND CATALOG.Course_Effective_Date <= class.START_DT
  AND CATALOG.Course_Expiration_Date >= class.START_DT
  )
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: There are classes within a course that start before the course's effective date?  That doesn't make sense.  PeopleSoft uses "effective date" fields so that a row of data should not be used prior to its effective date or after its obsolete date.  Why are there classes that start prior to the course's effective date?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider refactoring your design and adding something like CourseId to class, that way your join would be simple and more efficient...

if you want to keep the current design, you can use function ADDDATE, to add some time to class.START_DT, for example, add 10 days to start_date before comparing it with Course_Effective_Date:

```
CATALOG.Course_Effective_Date <= ADDDATE(day, 10, class.START_DT)
```

This way, the class can start up to 10 days before Course:

```
Select crse_id, institution, class_start_date, class_end_date
FROM PS_CLASS_TBL class
Inner join PS_CRSE_CATALOG CATALOG ON 
(
  CATALOG.CRSE_ID = class.CRSE_ID AND
  Catalog.INSTITUTION = class.INSTITUTION AND
  CATALOG.Course_Effective_Date <= ADDDATE(day, 10, class.START_DT) AND
  CATALOG.Course_Expiration_Date >= class.START_DT
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this method, I use MS SQL server database. I forgot to mention that in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

If any kind of overlap is possible, you may need to go as far as this:

```
Select crse_id, institution, class_start_date, class_end_date
FROM PS_CLASS_TBL class
Inner join PS_CRSE_CATALOG CATALOG ON 
(
CATALOG.CRSE_ID = class.CRSE_ID and
Catalog.INSTITUTION = class.INSTITUTION 
AND (
  CATALOG.Course_Effective_Date BETWEEN class.START_DT AND class.END_DT
  OR
  CATALOG.Course_Expiration_Date BETWEEN class.START_DT AND class.END_DT
  )
)
```